# Laravel Eloquent relationship with more than one join column

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm new to laravel and try to use Eloquent. 
Assuming there is the following database structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `a` (
  `userid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `aid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `p` (
  `userid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `pid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `aid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `text` text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `a` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`userid`,`aid`);
ALTER TABLE `p` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`userid`,`pid`);
```

Now I want a relation between the tables:

p contains a with p.userid=a.userid AND p.aid=a.aid

How can I do a relationship with more than one column?

Comment: I tried with hasmany but it seems that there can only be added one column for foreign_key parameter.

Answer (score 0):

First I want to mention that if you can't find a straight solution, there is always a workaround. The reason why you cannot do a relationship with more than one column in one table is that you need the same number of columns in the other table. So if you had 2 columns of type `int` in the first table, you need 2 columns of type `int` in the second table aswell to link them both. And as I see from what you provided, you are repeating data which suggests that your database is not normalized. I would suggest you do the following:

```
CREATE TABLE `a` (
    `userid` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `aid` int(11) NOT NULL unique,
    `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `p` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `userid` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `pid` int(11) NOT NULL unique,
    `text` text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `a` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`userid`);
ALTER TABLE `p` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
ALTER TABLE `p` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`userid`) REFERENCES `a` (`userid`)
```

This is what I think that is more suitable for you. However to answer your question, since you are using laravel in the `a model` do this:

```
class A extends Eloquent{
    public function p(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\P','userid') 
       // or hasMany
    }
    public function p(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\P','aid') 
        // or hasMany
    }
}
```

and the same thing in the `p model`

```
class P extends Eloquent{
    public function a(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\A','userid') 
        //or belongsTO
    }
    public function a(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\A','pid') 
       //or belongsTO
    }
}
```

**NOTE**

**PLEASE** keep in mind that the method belongsTo or hasMany is decided by your database model, on how you defined the database.

Comment: I think you completely messed up the data structure... Primary Key for a is the userid and the aid. aid is only unique for every userid. the same with table p. And you have no reference from table p to a except the userid. But every entry in p is referenced to one entry in a. An entry in p belongs to the entry in a where p.userid=a.userid AND p.aid = a.aid. Redeclaring function a (or p) doesn't work either